# Database importing error

Tags: mysql, database, import

I am new to MySQL, I can export and import the databases in my local phpmyadmin, but When i am trying to import a database to my server, showing the following error
" #1142 - CREATE command denied to user 'C163071_user'@'127.0.0.1' for table 'test' "
I don't know what is the reason for it, can anybody help me...

Comment: do you have privileges to create a table ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are getting is very brief. Unfortunately I have also used phpmyadmin before so I know the pain you are going through.

I would suggest to check your user privileges and also check that there are no concurrent users accessing the database (I'm not sure if phpmyadmin disallows concurrent access, but I wouldn't be surprised).

Comment: Hi Samuel Davis, It was correct your direction to the user privilages, i given all privilages to the user in server, now it is ok...Thank you very much Mr.Samuel Davis

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. Good luck with the rest of your project!

Answer (score 0):

If you're a customer of a web hosting company then this is likely a permissions issue. Customers will be denied the ability to create or drop MySQL databases at-will. Instead you will be limited to a single MySQL database that is either already created for you or can be created for you on your behalf via your web hosting control panel. If neither of these apply them contact your host for support.

EDIT: ah, I see the issue is with creating tables, not databases. This still sounds like a permissions issue. I suggest you contact your host for support.

Comment: Hi David, it was helped your word 'permission issue', i given all the permission to the user in server, now it is ok, Thank you Mr. David